# NSAttributedString: how to make multiline in another NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, nsattributedstring, nsparagraphstyle

I am trying to create a multiline separate text in another text to achieve the below text style.

[image]

I have tried the below code to produce the goal but the third part of the code is creating a issue (with medium font)

[image]

```
    private func createLimitedDetailText() -> NSAttributedString {
        let totalText = "Attension, only\n 6 spaces\n left!"
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: totalText, attributes: [
            .font: FontFamily.OpenSans.light.font(size: 29.0),
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
            ])

        let bigText = attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: FontFamily.OpenSans.extrabold.font(size: 70), range: NSRange(location: 17, length: 1))
        let medium = attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: FontFamily.OpenSans.semibold.font(size: 29), range: NSRange(location: 18, length: 14))

        let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: textRange)

        return attributedString
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible using only one `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: I’m okay with using multiple NSAttributedString. At the moment i am doing some experiments with baselineOffset but because the third part is 2 lines its creating issues.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering the answer, below code generates the exact same result:

```
    private func createLimitedDetailText() -> NSAttributedString {
        let totalText = "Attension, only\n 6"
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 0.90
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: totalText, attributes: [
            .font: FontFamily.OpenSans.light.font(size: 29.0),
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
            ])

        attributedString.addAttribute(.font, value: FontFamily.OpenSans.extrabold.font(size: 70), range: NSRange(location: 17, length: 1))

        let paragraphStyle2 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle2.lineHeightMultiple = 0.30
        paragraphStyle2.alignment = .center

        let attributedString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "    spaces\n     left!", attributes: [
            .font: FontFamily.OpenSans.semibold.font(size: 29.0),
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
            .baselineOffset: 35,
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle2
            ])
        attributedString.append(attributedString2)

        return attributedString
    }
```